# Python split iterables into combinations

Tags: python

given a iterable `'ABCD'`, I'd like to get all `(1,3)` pairs, eg:

```
('A', 'BCD'),
('B', 'ACD'),
('C', 'ABD'),
('D', 'ABC')
```

I've found `itertools.combination`, however, it can only give `['BCD', 'ACD', 'ABD', 'ABC']`, not including the `1` part.

it there an easy way to do this in python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
x = 'ABCD'
[(x[i], x[:i] + x[i+1:]) for i in range(len(x))]
# Outputs:
# [('A', 'BCD'), ('B', 'ACD'), ('C', 'ABD'), ('D', 'ABC')]
```

Comment: `join` is useless. Concatenation of the slices of the string gives string                    `>>> [(x[i], x[:i] + x[i+1:]) for i in range(len(x))]`
`[('A', 'BCD'), ('B', 'ACD'), ('C', 'ABD'), ('D', 'ABC')]`

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to use set differences to identify to the part excluded by the generated combination:

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> population = set('ABCD')
>>> for group in combinations(population, 3):
        remainder = population.difference(group)
        result = ''.join(remainder), ''.join(group)
        print(result)

('D', 'ACB')
('B', 'ACD')
('C', 'ABD')
('A', 'CBD')
```

This technique works for partitions other than just `(1, 3)`.  For example, here are the `(2, 3)` partitions:

```
>>> population = set('ABCDE')
>>> for group in combinations(population, 3):
    remainder = population.difference(group)
    result = ''.join(remainder), ''.join(group)
    print(result)


('ED', 'ACB')
('BD', 'ACE')
('BE', 'ACD')
('CD', 'ABE')
('CE', 'ABD')
('CB', 'AED')
('AD', 'CBE')
('AE', 'CBD')
('AB', 'CED')
('AC', 'BED')
```

Comment: For `(1,3)`, you don't need `combinations`; iterating directly over `population` gives you the singleton item in `group`, with `remainder` being the remaining triplet.

Comment: Which is more useful on StackOverflow, an answer hardwired to a trivial special case or a general purpose solution that works for a variety of cases and shows how to use the language effectively?

Comment: I think it's presumptuous to call the scenario in the actual question a "trivial" special case. If that's the output needed, there's no need to invoke an unnecessary function call. Use `combinations` where warranted.